# How test user entry from a ruby gtk?

Tags: ruby, gtk

How can I test and execute a command after a gtk dialog? I have the following.

```
dialog.default_response = Gtk::Dialog::RESPONSE_OK
label1 = Gtk::Label.new("Test1")
label2 = Gtk::Label.new("Test2")
label3 = Gtk::Label.new("Test3")
label4 = Gtk::Label.new("Test4")

resultest1 = Gtk::Entry.new
resultest2 = Gtk::Entry.new
resultest3 = Gtk::Entry.new
resultest4 = Gtk::Entry.new


table = Gtk::Table.new(4, 2, false)
table.attach_defaults(label1, 0, 1, 0, 1)
table.attach_defaults(label2, 0, 1, 1, 2)
table.attach_defaults(label3, 0, 1, 2, 3)
table.attach_defaults(label4, 0, 1, 3, 4) 
table.attach_defaults(resultest1,   1, 2, 0, 1)
table.attach_defaults(resultest2,   1, 2, 1, 2)
table.attach_defaults(resultest3,   1, 2, 2, 3)
table.attach_defaults(resultest4,   1, 2, 3, 4)
table.row_spacings = 5
table.column_spacings = 5
table.border_width = 10

dialog.vbox.add(table)
dialog.show_all

# Run the dialog and output the data if user okays it
dialog.run do |response|
  if response == Gtk::Dialog::RESPONSE_OK
    print "Do something with response 1 of the user: %s\n" % [resultest1.text]
    print "Do something with response 2 of the user: %s\n" % [resultest2.text]
    print "Do something with response 3 of the user: %s\n" % [resultest3.text]
    print "Do something with response 4 of the user: %s\n" % [resultest4.text]
  end
end
dialog.destroy
}
```

And I want to do some commands with the user response. For example one command on the same line with response 1 and 2 like unix sample commands. If question 1 is what wifi card you use and question 2 is what channel to listen to, I want to be able to do the following after the Gtk::dialog:
airodump-ng -c ${canal} ${wificard}

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this question relate to the Gtk dialog somehow or is it just "how to execute system command from ruby"?

Comment: HI, it is about Gtk dialog, i know use command in ruby with system, the objective is now to regist user entry and send them in a command after Gtk dialog.At his point im little confused for send a command after the dialog box with the user entry.

Answer (score -1):

Ok im trying to fix the problem, i just change line 105:

```
dialog.run do |response|
  if response == Gtk::Dialog::RESPONSE_OK
    system "airodump-ng %s\n" % [card.text] % [canal.text]
```

That work but after my app stop with the following errors:

```
rom test4.rb:105:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
     from test4.rb:103:in `run'
     from test4.rb:103:in `block in <main>'
```

How i can use a sample command after the gtk dialog like that:

```
system "airodump-ng -c %s\n" [channelnumber.text] [card.text]
```

What does the operator % exactly ? and why i can't use all airodump-ng flags in one command line ? If i start like that:

```
system "airodump-ng %s\n" [card.text] -c [channelnumber.text]
```

Or like that:

```
system "airodump-ng %s\n" [card.text] "-c" [channelnumber.text]
```

I have this error:

```
test4.rb:105:in `block (2 levels) in <main>': undefined local variable or method `c' for main:Object
```

I know how work system with a sample ruby script but i just want to understand how link the parameters of user entry with a shell command using GTK, in this example with airodump-ng command.